# django python eval

Tags: python, django

I have some code snippet of code I'd like to abstract to a function that only has one small change that needs to be dynamic

```
if myUser.profile.get_setting_c == True :
# below does not work but you get the idea, how 
if myUser.profile.eval('get_setting_c') == True :
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

`getattr(myUser.profile, 'get_setting_c')`

BTW, using `eval` is considered bad practice in python, see [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) .

Comment: Just to complete: assign to a variable like "attr = getattr(myUser.profile, 'get_setting_c'); if attr == True:"

Answer (score -1):

Why not

```
if eval('myUser.profile.get_setting_c') == True:
```

or

```
def fun(setting):
    return eval('myUser.profile.%s' % setting)

if fun('get_setting_c') == True:
```

?

Comment: Becasue func(‘get_setting_c or True’) gives True